# Need help in python with deleting a dictionary inside a list in json

Tags: python, json

So, I have an assignment and I need to build an administration for the borrowed books. I have a list of books(100 books) in a listofbooks.json. From listofbooks.json, I can add books to the other jsonfile named Borrowedbooks.json, but the problem is I can't "unloan" the book. So what I try to do to "unloan" a book is:

```
import json
def DeleteBook(p):

for x in B:
    if x['title'] == C[p]['title']:
        del B[p]
        with open('Borrowedbooks.json','w') as output:
            json.dump(B,output,indent=2)
            print("Deleted succesfully!")
            break


    else:
        print("The book that you want to delete doesn't exist")
        break


C = json.load(open('ListOfBooks.json'))
B = json.load(open('Borrowedbooks.json'))
```

The problem with this code is that if someone loans a book with ID 2 and ID 4, it is checking the indexes but what I want is that it checks the ID of the book but that's the point what I can't do. The index is incorrect at the borrowbooks.jsonfile and it is going to the else statement.
So on my ListOfBooks.jsonfile, the book with ID 2 is on index 2, but in borrowedbooks.json the book with ID 2 is on index 0
The borrowedbooks.json looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "author": "Dante Alighieri",
    "country": "Italy",
    "imageLink": "images/the-divine-comedy.jpg",
    "language": "Italian",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_Comedy\n",
    "pages": 928,
    "title": "The Divine Comedy",
    "year": 1315
  },
  {
    "ID": 3,
    "author": "Unknown",
    "country": "Sumer and Akkadian Empire",
    "imageLink": "images/the-epic-of-gilgamesh.jpg",
    "language": "Akkadian",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_of_Gilgamesh\n",
    "pages": 160,
    "title": "The Epic Of Gilgamesh",
    "year": -1700
  }
 ]
```

My question is how can I make a function where the user writes the book ID and it will delete the dictionary inside the borrowedbooks.json.

Comment: why write the whole JSON to another JSON if it is borrowed? you can simply write the ID of a borrowed book to another dictionary where the key is the ID and the value is `loaned` or `available` that way removing the item from the lookup is faster

Comment: Because for the assignment I need 2 seperated json files, on the listofbooks I also need to add books and i need an administration file with the borrowed books. (what I understand from your question)

Comment: the administration file does not need all the information about the books since that already exists in the listofbooks, all it needs is the id of the book in that file, like `{'2': 'borrowed', '4': 'borrowed'}` etc... then removing and unloaning books becomes a lot simpler

Comment: Oh, yes I understand it now. I will also change my loanbook function but how should I approach it like the way you are telling me?

Comment: your listofbooks stays the same, when a book gets borrowed write out its id to the separate file, when it comes back from being borrowed just remove it from the dictionary using `pop`

Comment: Thanks, im gonna try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from what I am understanding is that when you input 2 into a returned book ID variable or array, you can only get index of 2 instead of ID of 2.

What you can do is use  `bookID = json.get('ID')` and a function to check similar to what you did up there. You are using arrays so keep that in mind.